# Render Layout issue while placing widgets in Column

Tags: flutter

The below page is working fine . Where i have a column and then Flexible widgets .

It has below issues , i tried resolving them but i think the Render Layout error are occuring .

1. The whole page is not scrollable . As the column cannot be scrollable and i can put them in list view instead but then it is showing Render error .
2. The app bar is taking lot of space also , how can i shift it upwards , i tried setting PreferredSize property of app bar but again there was Render layout error and the below column overlapped .

How can i make this page correct , i am not very happy with the way i have included the widgets here .

```
                 @override
                 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
                   return Scaffold(
                     appBar: AppBar(
                       elevation: 0,
                       backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                       title: Text("View All"),
                       actions: <Widget>[
                         IconButton(
                           icon: Icon(
                             Icons.search_outlined,
                           ),
                           onPressed: () {
                             Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(CartScreen.routeName);
                           },
                         ),
                       ],
                     ),
                     drawer: AppDrawer(),
                     body: _isLoading
                         ? Center(
                             child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                           )
                         : Padding(
                             padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                             child: Column(
                               children: [
                                 Flexible(
                                   flex: 3,
                                   child: Padding(
                                     padding: const EdgeInsets.all(6),
                                     child: TextButton(
                                       child: Center(
                                         child: Column(
                                           mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                           mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                                           children: [
                                             Text(
                                               'Sale  For Everyone ',
                                               style: TextStyle(
                                                   color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
                                             ),
                                             Text(
                                               'Buy 2 Get 1 Free ',
                                               style: TextStyle(
                                                   color: Colors.white, fontSize: 16),
                                             )
                                           ],
                                         ),
                                       ),
                                       style: ButtonStyle(
                                         backgroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(
                                             Color.fromRGBO(229, 0, 16, 1)),
                                       ),
                                       onPressed: () {},
                                     ),
                                   ),
                                 ),
                                 Flexible(
                                   flex: 2,
                                   child: ListView(
                                       scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                       children: _getListData()),
                                 ),
                                 Flexible(
                                   flex: 1,
                                   child: IconButton(
                                     icon: Icon(
                                       Icons.tune_outlined,
                                     ),
                                     onPressed: () {
                                       showGeneralDialog(
                                         context: context,
                                         barrierColor:
                                             Colors.white.withOpacity(1), // Background color
                                         barrierDismissible: false,
                                         barrierLabel: 'Dialog',
                                         transitionDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 400),
                                         pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) {
                                           return FilterScreen();
                                         },
                                       );
                                     },
                                   ),
                                 ),
                                 Flexible(flex: 9, child: ProductsGrid(_showOnlyFavorites)),
                               ],
                             ),
                           ),
                   );
                 }
                

                getListData() {
                 List<Widget> widgets = [];
                 for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                   widgets.add(Padding(
                       padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 2),
                       child: Column(
                         children: <Widget>[
                           Padding(
                             padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                             child: TextButton(
                                 onPressed: () {},
                                 child: Padding(
                                   padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15, right: 15),
                                   child: Text(
                                     'Flip  - Flops ',
                                     style: TextStyle(
                                         fontSize: 12,
                                         color: Colors.white,
                                         fontFamily: 'Lato',
                                         fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                   ),
                                 ),
                                 style: ButtonStyle(
                                     backgroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(
                                         Color.fromRGBO(37, 109, 164, 1)),
                                     shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                                         RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                             borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                                             side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black))))),
                           ),
                         ],
                       )));
                 }
                 return widgets;
```

[image: It is appearing something like this .]